# Select element that resides between two elements

Tags: xpath

Thought this was going to be an easy query... my limited XPath knowledge certainly does not help and I'm probably complicating things.

Trying to locate any EFFECT tags that reside between two SUBTASK tags.

```
<TOPIC>
 <TITLE/>
 <EFFECT/>            
 <SUBTASK>
 </SUBTASK>
 <EFFECT/>
 <SUBTASK>
 </SUBTASK>
</TOPIC>
```

Here's a false positive example:

```
<TC>
 <TCBODY>
  <TASK>
   <EFFECT/>
   <TITLE/>
   <TOPIC>
    <TITLE/>
    <EFFECT/>
    <SUBTASK>
     <EFFECT/>
    </SUBTASK>
   </TOPIC>
  </TASK>
 </TCBODY>
</TC>
```

**UPDATE:** The above question has been answered and the following expression worked:

```
//EFFECT[preceding-sibling::SUBTASK and following-sibling::SUBTASK]
```

Now trying to locate any EFFECT tag where the preceding-sibling and following-sibling are the same - no matter what the element name is.

Tried this expression but its returning too many false positives:

`//EFFECT[preceding-sibling::*[name()] = following-sibling::*[name()]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: can you edit the xml sample and show a more complete example with the added elements the causes false positives?  thanks

Comment: notice that your forth example which seems to be the most appropriate for what you describe has a missing letter in SUBASK; should be //EFFECT[preceding-sibling::SUBTASK and following-sibling::SUBTASK]

Comment: Thanks... a fat finger mistake on SUBTASK.  Working on getting a more complete example... in short the EFFECT tag is allowed just about anywhere within the document. I just want the ones in between two SUBTASKS.

Comment: then your fourth one should work well unless the xml is more complex than the example and we are missing something

Comment: Thank you... I just updated with a more complex example and I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: Well... I feel like an idiot; it looks like it was a fat finger mistake on the fourth example smh. Just ran it again and it did not bring back that first false positive.  Feel like a idiot but happy I was figuring it out!  Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: :) No worries, glad it got sorted now